# How do I create a Pandas Dataframe where the column set is different for each row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I essentially want something like this:

```
    A   B   C   D
1   v   v       v
2   v       v   v
3       v   v
```

where:

- row 1 has a value for columns A, B and D but doesn't have column C
- row 2 has a value for columns A, C and D but doesn't have column B
- row 3 has a value for columns B and C but doesn't have columns A and
  D.

As a bit of a back story, I am retrieving rows from Dynamo DB directly into a Pandas Dataframe and since each row in Dynamo is essentially a separate stand alone JSON object, I am frequently getting the above situation.  Some of my pandas function calls are failing with KeyError since the column doesn't even exist.  I want to recreate the situation so I can find a way to deal with it more gracefully.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `.loc`? Something like `df.loc[0, ['A', 'B', 'D']] = ['v', 'v', 'v']`.

Comment: Are you able to load the data in a dataframe? Could you show what your input data looks like and the expected output?

Comment: @ResidentSleeper - I have - when I do I get - KeyError: "None of [Index(['A', 'B', 'D'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: @FrancoPiccolo - Not that simple - we are dealing with watch data and it generates ~50 rows per second.  Essentially the row level JSON contains watch data that was measured that interval.  A lot of the columns are common to every row, but not every column.  As an example the activity column appears 3 times in 550 rows of watch data.

Comment: You have to create a dataframe first. `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])` Then try `df.loc[0, ['A', 'B', 'D']] = ['v', 'v', 'v']`.

Comment: I don't know that you have fully specified your problem.  Why haven't you included a row with A,B,C but not D, or row B,C,D but not A?  Are you trying to generate unique rows, or prevent duplicates from an external datasource, or?

Comment: OK - I sort of figured out how to do what I wanted: df = pd.DataFrame([{'A': 'v', 'B': 'v', 'D': 'v'}, {'A':'v', 'B':'v', 'C':'v'}, {'B':'v', 'C':'v'}]).  More importantly, I figured out that it is not possible to have rows in a dataframe without all the same columns.  The error I am getting is because the dataframe doesn't have the activity column.

Comment: @ResidentSleeper - I was trying to avoid specifying the columns on the creation of the Dataframe.  I was constructing the dataframe using: df = pd.DataFrame().  I realized that I was trying to do something that pandas wasn't capable of doing.  Namely, create a dataframe where the each row had a different set of columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all unique permutations of the list `['v', 'v', 'v', '']` for example, this can be done with `itertools`:

```
import itertools

data_list = ['v', 'v', 'v', '']
data = set(itertools.permutations(data_list))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Comment: I don't think he only has `v` in his data. Those were more of symbolic as to where he has data and where he doesn't.

Comment: @Quang Hoang - That is 100% correct.  I used a v to indicate that there was a value, but the value wasn't important for the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This generates a dataframe, but the 1st row has a 'C' column, the 2nd row has a 'D' column and the 3rd row has an 'A' and 'D' columns despite me not specifying them:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'A': 'v', 'B': 'v', 'D': 'v'}, {'A':'v', 'B':'v', 'C':'v'}, {'B':'v', 'C':'v'}])
```

I don't think it is possible to create a dataframe where only certain rows have certain columns.